# jQuery ajax - blank response returned

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am trying to use jQuery ajax to get some values from the database and then return them in an array.

I have used the same code several times before but this time, no response is being returned. Although the post values are the correct values that I would expect. Here is the javascript code that I am using:

```
$.ajax({ url: '/BlogArchive.asmx/ChangePost'
                    , type: 'POST'
                    , contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                    , data: '{FileName:"' + FileName + '"}'
                    , dataType: 'json'
                    , success: function (data) 
                    {
                        var arrayList = data.d;

                        var BlogPostTitle = $(".BlogPostTitle")[0];
                        var BlogPostDate = $(".BlogPostDate")[0];
                        var BlogPostContent = $(".BlogPostContent")[0];

                        $(BlogPostTitle).html(arrayList[0]);
                        $(BlogPostDate).html(arrayList[1]);
                        $(BlogPostContent).html(arrayList[2]);

                    }
//                    , error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
//                    {
//                        //There was an error
//                        alert('dfd');
//                    }
            });
```

The only javascript error that I am receiving is that data is null, which I would expect as the response is blank.

It seems that the name of the web method that I am calling from my javascript is not even being read, because if I changed 'ChangePost' to 'ChangePost1' for example, it still returns a blank response, although I would expect an error message saying that the web method can't be found.

It seems that it does recognise that the BlogArchive.asmx web service exists because if I put something that would create an error in the VB code, the error appears as the response.

I am sure this must be something simple that I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you're setting the POST variables [data attribute] in to a JSON string and not just a JSON object?

Comment: @bradchristie - http://encosia.com/2008/06/05/3-mistakes-to-avoid-when-using-jquery-with-aspnet-ajax/

Answer (score 0):

```
, data: '{FileName:"' + FileName + '"}'
```

Seems odd. You probably meant:

```
, data: {FileName: FileName}
```

(or `'FileName=' + FileName`)

Furthermore, did you inspect the request (and response) via FireBug or similar?

Comment: yeah use firebug! it will save you huge amounts of time in troubleshooting these sort of issues! +1

Comment: See the "JSON, objects, and strings: oh my!" section of this [blog post](http://encosia.com/2008/06/05/3-mistakes-to-avoid-when-using-jquery-with-aspnet-ajax/) to see why the string literal is required with asp.Net

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I've tried changing the 'data' line to the ways you suggested but I still get the same blank response. Also, yes I do use FireBug - that's where I noticed that the response was empty. I can see in the 'Post' tab that the values are being sent correctly as well.

Comment: @jball Ahh, I had a sneaking suspicion that my ignorance of ASP.Net would shine through :)

Comment: @Leah I guess my initial inspection did nothing good (and you can read from my comment above that ASP.Net is not something I know a great deal about). Sorry and good luck!

Comment: @jensgram No, unfortunately it didn't work, but thanks very much for your help - it is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You should try using jQuery [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) with the minimal arguments.

Another thing, when you are using JSON with jQuery, if the answer data are not wellformed 
(like a space before / after the starting JSON string) could lead to a blank answer from
jQuery.

Be sure using traditionnal AJAX with jQuery that your answered data are correct.